# Why Android Emulator is Way Slower than iPhone Simulator?

Tags: android, iphone, android-emulator, ios-simulator

Just Curious. Did Apple do an awesome job with their iPhone simulator?

When Compared,The android Emulator running on i7 and iPhone simulator on i3. The iPhone simulator is faster than the real iPhone.

Did I fail to set things up right?

Comment: Yes that's true, The `emulator` (FYI) is slower then simulator.

Comment: Android emulator in my experience is exponentially faster than iOS Simulator.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's a matter of architectural decisions:

- iOS simulator runs native code, directly on your CPU - the project has to be recompiled for x86 architecture to be used with simulator. The simulator itself simply emulates all the iOS APIs.
- Android emulator, on the other hand, uses [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) to run ARM (or x86, but ARM is more popular) CPU virtual machine, with all the software stack on top of it - Linux kernel, Android system image, etc. Think of it as an emulated hardware.

It's a sort of trade off - the way iOS does it is much faster, but it is harder to make it 100% compatible with the target system. For Apple it was perhaps a bit simpler, as iOS and Mac OS have many things in common.

For Android it makes a lot of sense to emulate the whole stack - it is easier to build cross-platform SDK, easier to test some system level components with it, etc. It's simply a different ecosystem, with different goals. Don't forget, that Android emulator can be used e.g. to test native ARM libraries compiled with Android NDK.

Today the Android emulator performance is more or less acceptable, but it was just a disaster in the early Android days. That said, personally I think that fast, API-level native simulator for Android would be a great addition to the SDK, making it possible to test less demanding projects much faster.

Interesting reading: http://logic-explained.blogspot.com/2011/09/why-is-there-no-x86-native-emulator-for.html

Comment: This answer is somewhat old, but still good info about the ARM emulator. There's newer emulators using Intel HAX. If you have an Intel CPU with virtualization set up, you'll get a much higher performance. The graphics part will still be slow, but you can drop the resolution to compensate for that. I had success running Android x86 on a VM as well (ctrl-F1, type netcfg on VM. Ctrl-F7 to get back to the GUI. On dev machine, adb connect <insert VM's IP address here>). The Kitkat Android x86 versions are quite excellent if you don't have your app locked in portrait

Comment: See this: http://jakewharton.com/android-needs-a-simulator/

Answer (score 2):

iphone ,iphone simulator,apple laptop ,xcode  are apple products

but android
windows-Microsoft
android -Google
eclipse -eclipse vendor

these tools are different vendors that why android simulator slow.

i am just kidding :)

Answer (score 2):

Apple Simulator is created using system configuration means it will take the System's ram, memory,cache automatically you don't have to configure it, so an Iphone Simulator is not act as real device but in case of Android one has to provide all the configuration details before creating the emulator,Android emulator to a great extent will act as real device but can be much slower than an Iphone Simulator.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's true, The `emulator` (FYI) is slower then simulator.

> Does apple did an awesome job with the iPhone simulator?

No other developer can answer this because iOS is not open-source.

> Did I fail to set things up right?

No, you are right at everything.

Answer (score 1):

First of all Android does not have a Simulator it has an [Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html).
Secondly I believe the speed of the Emulator depends on your machine config. Better the config the better it will run provided you have created the `AVD` properly and given it ample memory.

Answer (score 1):

That's simple:

Android Emulates real device, so real architeture and really close behaivour and layout.

In other hands apple simulator is not an emulator, so you can't expect real behaviour, but it has a close layout, which mainly solves for IOS, as you needs only 1 device to test the app behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK has an emulator, Whereas ios SDK has simulator.

A simulator behaves similar to something else, but is implemented in an entirely different way. It provides the basic behavior of a system but may not necessarily abide by all of the rules of the system being simulated. It is there to give you an idea about how something works. It uses Desktop resources like processor, ram etc.,

An emulator is a system that behaves exactly like something else, and abides by all of the rules of the system being emulated. It is effectively a complete replication of another system, right down to being binary compatible with the emulated system's inputs and outputs, but operating in a different environment to the environment of the original emulated system.

Thus simulator will be definitely fast compared to emulator.

Answer (score 0):

The Android simulator is actually an emulator, designed to mimic a mobile device running Android, meaning it emulates the hardware running Android OS, to make it as close to 100% identical as possible. The JVM converts Java bytecode into ARM instructions that are decoded by the emulator.

The iOS simulator works at a higher level, simulating the operating system and its libraries, translating OS calls into OS X implementations and simulating events in the other direction like device rotation or low memory conditions. When you run an app on the iOS simulator, the app is compiled into x86 that runs natively on your Mac. Unlike the Android emulator, your iOS app won't run out of memory in the simulator because it's not constrained to any particular iOS device's memory limitations.